# proof of finding modular inverse of number using Euler's totient

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

If it is true prove that

> for every $a,m$ ($a,m$ are co-primes), there exists $a^{-1}$ such that $a\cdot a^{-1} \equiv 1\bmod{m}$, which can be found by $$a^{\phi(m)-1}$$ where $\phi(m)$ is the totient function.

I need a proof of this statement that $a^{t(m)-1}$ is mod inverse of $a$.

You may also prove $a^{\phi(m)} ≡ 1 \mod m$.

Comment: Welcome to Math SX! This is *Euler's theorem* in modular arithmetic, an extension of *Little Fermat's theorem*. You can see proofs on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem), for instance.

Answer (score 1):

This is true: $a^{\phi(m)}\equiv1\pmod m$, when gcd($a,m)=1$, and hence the modular inverse for $a$ is $a^{\phi(m)-1}$. This is an old theorem, (more than 250 years ago) due to Euler and is found in all textbooks on elementary number theory, along with Fermat's Little Theorem.  This is a conceptual fact.  However, for large numbers this is not a practical way to compute the modular inverse: because this presupposes factorization of $m$ is known. At present  there is no formula for $\phi(m)$ without knowing the factorization of $m$.

In fact the security of the RSA cryptosystem rests on the practical difficulty of factorizing large numbers.

The usual way for finding the modular inverse is carrying out Euclid's algorithm for gcd with extra details (keep track of quotients in every division, not just remainders). This is called Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

**Proof for a<sup>φ(m)</sup> ≡ 1 (mod m):**


Consider the set of numbers $A =${$n_1, n_2, ... n_{\phi(m)}$}$\pmod{m}$ such that the elements of the set are the numbers relatively prime to $m$ (As we know that there exist only φ(m) numbers that are relatively prime to m). Now multiply each element of set $A$ with a number $a$ and form another set $B = ${ $an_1, an_2, ... an_{\phi(m)}$}$\pmod{m}$ where $GCD(a, m) = 1$. As multiplying the numbers of set $A$ with a number $a$ which is relatively prime with $m$ holds the property that  all the elements in set $B$ are relatively prime to $m$. Also all the elements in the set $B$ are distinct. In other words, each element of $B$ is congruent to one of $A$. This means that 
 $n_1 n_2 ... n_{\phi(m)} \equiv an_1 \cdot an_2 ... an_{\phi(m)}$$\pmod{m}$ 
 $a^{\phi (m)} \cdot (n_1 n_2 ... n_{\phi(m)}) \equiv n_1 n_2 ... n_{\phi(m)}$$\pmod{m}$ 
 $a^{\phi (m)} \equiv 1$$\pmod{m}$ as desired.
Note that dividing by $n_1 n_2 ... n_{\phi(m)}$ is allowed since it is relatively prime to $m$.

Now multiply $a^{-1}$ on both sides which makes $a^{\phi (m)-1} \equiv a^{-1}$ $\pmod{m}$ which can be written as $a^{-1} \equiv a^{\phi (m)-1}$ $\pmod{m}$.

Hence we can say that modular multiplicative inverse of $a$ under$\pmod{m}$ is $a^{\phi (m)-1}$.

Hope it helps. 

[Useful Link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Euler%27s_Totient_Theorem)